# VB.net find max value in excel range

Tags: vb.net, excel

New to VB coding, so please bear with me.

A Windows forms project I'm working on (for both personal interest and as a challenge) is to automate a process at work whereby a job coming into the office will have several items attached to it requiring attention. These items are booked into a SQL DB using a bespoke software (which can not be avoided) and then typed into a spreadsheet. I'm trying to automate this process somewhat. I have succeeded (with stackoverflow's assistance) to create a connection from my form to the SQL Server, run a query, store the results in a dataset and transfer that first set of data to my excel.

However, each day I need to append the sheet with new items/entries. The entries in the DB have a unique consecutive ID number so my idea is to run a Select query for entries > the highest ID already written to excel.

I have already identified the last row containing data (lrow) because I'll need that anyway... (xlsht is my active worksheet)

```
    Dim lrow as long = 0
    With xlSht
        lrow = .range("C" & .rows.count).end(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).row
    End With
```

Can I use this to identify the highest ID number from the range C6:C(lrow), or (C:C) as has been suggested. The spreadsheet data isn't in ID order so just selecting the last filled cell in that column won't work.

using Application.max("C:C") errors as "'max' is not a member of system.windows.forms.application" and my lack of experience means i don't yet know how to fix that!

I've been searching for suggestions but can only find code ideas in VBA and my lack of knowledge is such that I can't easily translate or understand it. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Many thanks.

EDIT: as a workaround, until i know more, i've created a hidden column in the spreadsheet, a cell (T6) of which contains the function 'max(C:C)' and i am then reading that value into my VB code as

```
    Dim maxvalue As Integer
    maxvalue = xlSht.range("T6").Value
```

...but i'd like to remove that eventually.

Thanks

Comment: If C1:C5 don't have large values perhaps you can use Application.Max(C:C)?

Comment: I would be prudent to specify how you are working with this e.g. office automation, Oledb data provider etc.

Comment: Karen, 'll happily provide a bit more info! As a learning experience and interest, i offered to try and automate this process at work. A job coming in to the office contains several items. We use a management program to book these items in (this process cannot be worked-around, unfortunately), and that program stores the data in a SQL 2012 DB. I have written some VB.net in VS2013 to read that db and extract three fields from each items relating to that job to populate a spreadsheet. Additional items may then be submitted under the same job and i'm trying to write code to add...

Comment: ...the new item under the existing ones. As all the items are held in the DB with unique consecutive ID number i can use this field to extract only new items once i know the highest number currently in the spreadsheet in column 'C'. As the data isn't held in numerical order in the excel sheet, i can't just read the last cell... Hence my need for code  get the highest.

Comment: This question is really about getting the max value in a range. Everything else here is just noise and might not be helpful. We don't really need to know the details of what you're doing after all. IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the WorksheetFunction to get the max value.

```
    Dim xlapp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    xlapp = xlSht.Parent.Application
    Debug.Print xlapp.WorksheetFunction.Max(xlSht.Range("C:C"))
```

If you already have the application object, you just need the last line. I usually use an imports statements:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

and of course you'll also need a project reference to Excel interop.

Comment: thanks for that suggestion - I'll give it a go tomorrow

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly what i was looking for.